# jQuery UI widgets stop working after minifying

Tags: jquery-ui, gruntjs, requirejs, minify

Recently I had to update our jquery version from 1.x to 3.5. With that I also had to update Jquery UI to 1.12. I used the opportunity to import our js dependencies as node_modules instead of just having a copy in our repository.

When running our WebApp within the IDE everything works fine and as expected. However, as soon as I build the .exe with pyInstaller (running a grunt task to minify everything into a single app.min.js), I get the error message "g.sortable is not a function". The same problem occurs with jquery.transit.

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    // snip
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "jquery.iframe-transport": "1.0.0",
    "jquery.transit": "0.9.12",
  }
}
```

configuration.js:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
   // snip
   'ui.sortable': '<...>/3rdparty/js/node_modules/angular-ui-sortable/dist/sortable',
   'jquery': '<...>/3rdparty/js/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery',
   'jquery.transit': '<...>/3rdparty/js/node_modules/jquery.transit/jquery.transit',
   'jquery-ui': '<...>/3rdparty/js/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui',
  }
})
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('<...>/3rdparty/js/package.json'),
      requirejs: {
        compile: {
          options: {
            baseUrl: '<...>/js',
            mainConfigFile: '<...>/js/configuration.js',
            optimize: 'none'
          }
        }
      },
    ts: { ... },
    sass: { ... },
    uglify: {
      'js': {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            src: [
              'app/**/*.js',
              '!app/**/3rdparty/**/*.js',
              '!app/<...>/js/configuration.js',
              '!app/<...>/js/patch.js'
            ]
          }
        ],
        options: {
          compress: true,
          mangle: false
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Again, the javascript files seem to work together properly as there is no problem when I start the webservice in pycharm. It's only when I compile and minify everything that the jquery UI widgets stop working. Other external libraries for whose I started using npm work perfectly fine.

I am kinda clueless at this point.

Comment: I thought it was `jquery.ui.sortable`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Twisty: There are plenty of packages, but no `jquery.ui.sortable`. I even tried it with a pre built jquerUI that already includes the `sortable` widget. Without success so far. Maybe I am asking the wrong questions, though.

Comment: Are you restoring your packages when deploying to your environment(dev, live)? How are you deploying?

Comment: @AlexLeo the issue was, that the older version had a different loading mechanism, so I had to manually import it once somewhere. Will write an answer to my problem later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution to my problem was to just

```
import 'jquery.transit';
import 'jquery.ui';
```

In one of my TypeScript files. Apparently in the whole project that never happened anywhere. It worked before my updates because the jqueryUI version we used had the AMD part of it commented out.